# Create a SAS token for Specific blob and not other blob in same storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

Regardless of the type of storage accounts in Azure. Is there any way to create SAS token in Powershell or portal(doesn't seem like) that has exclusive access to a blob and not rest of blobs in the same storage account

Seems below command is available but maybe for different storage account type and not necessary for a blob

```
New-AzStorageBlobSASToken;
```

I did create SAS token with below PowerShell script but this token is for the whole blob service

```
$SA = Get-AzStorageAccount | Select-Object StorageAccountName,ResourceGroupName,Location,SkuName,CreationTime | Out-GridView -PassThru
$key = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SA.ResourceGroupName -Name $SA.StorageAccountName
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SA.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key.value[0]
$sas = New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob, File, Table, Queue -ResourceType Service, Container, Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $context
Write-Output $sas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New-AzStorageBlobSASToken` does exactly that. It creates a SAS token for one specific blob (think of blob=file in this case)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageblobsastoken?view=azps-2.7.0#examples

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to create the SAS token. But when I'm trying to use it in Azure storage explorer I get this response, do you know what does that means:  Invalid resource in SAS token. Only blob container ('c') resources are supported.

Comment: @BenyaminFamili, it means that you cannot use blob_uri + sas_token to login into azure storage explorer, at least you need a container + sas_token. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-storage-explorer#log-in-to-storage-explorer) for details.